# Is Dune intended as an allegory of the Middle East?

Tags: dune

*Dune* is clearly inspired by the middle east — a barren, desert area controlling the one most important commodity in the world (spice/oil) without which all guild navigation/transportation cannot function. Ideas of resource scarcity also appear prevalent, according to Frank Herbert, "The scarce water of *Dune* is an exact analog of oil scarcity. CHOAM is OPEC."

There are also similarities in the language, e.g., in Fremen Sayyadina refers to a wise woman who is also the spiritual leader of the tribe. In Arabic it refers to "master" and often used in a religious context such as saying [ala Sayyidina Muhammad](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/198325/saying-sayyidina-when-invoking-blessings-upon-the-prophet-sallallaahu-alayhi-wa-sallam). Paul also refers to his global conquest as a religious Jihad.

Did Frank Herbert intend *Dune* to be a critique or allegory of the Middle East?

Comment: Read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel)).  Herbert started pulling together the threads of *Dune* in the late 1950s (the sea of sand, the ecology parts, spice) and [OPEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPEC) wasn't founded until 1960 and didn't become an economic force until the 1970s when they started to get better control of the production agreements.  Dune was serialized 1963-1965, so no, OPEC is not an inspiration, and the idea that the desert countries control production of a critical resource was not contemporaneous.

Comment: Wasn't Dune was published in 1965 -- 5 years after OPEC was founded. Frank Herbert himself said "The scarce water of Dune is an exact analog of oil scarcity. CHOAM is OPEC." I'm not sure I get your point.

Comment: Ecology - http://www.sinanvural.com/seksek/inien/tvd/tvd2.htm

Comment: Did you read the part where OPEC had no real power over pricing until 1973 when the OPEC members nationalized their oil industries?  Herbert could easily have made that comparison retrospectively, without it being part of his inspiration.  Oh, and Venezuela was one of the founding (and instigating) members, so it was never only about desert oil.

Comment: I'm used to allegory relating to past events. If you read the dedication in the first book, he claimed to write it for the "dry-land ecologists" of the future. He perhaps saw the way things were going and made an allegorical *prediction* you might say.

Comment: Respectfully David, is this relevant? Does this mean that oil scarcity did not exist in 1960? Why do you think that Frank couldn't see the parallel between formation of a largely middle east organization trying to push back against the unfair revenue practices of the 7 large oil companies in 1960 as a theme of Imperialism vs local control of resources -- like the Fremen vs the Harkonnen? I think I'll need more than "Frank  retroactively claimed he was inspired"

Comment: Thanks Valorum, Jiminy, greatly appreciate it. Do you want to write it as the answer and I'll accept. I confess I skipped the dedication and only thought about it after seeing the film recently.

Comment: @Valorum That's an amazing interview, thanks so much for the link!  How on Earth did you find it?

Comment: @DavidW - I seen it referenced on Reddit a few times.

Comment: Surely if it were an allegory the main planet would be named something obvious like Iraq-is.

Comment: Note that the parallels, while present, aren't particularly exact. CHOAM controls all trade in the Imperium, not just (or even mainly) Spice. And it isn't in any way associated with the Fremen in the way that OPEC is mainly associated with Arabs.

Comment: That great interview from @Valorum does show ecology as a prime focus, but suggests his interest in religious movements, particularly those in desert regions (not just the Arabian, he also mentions Kalahari), also became an important theme as he developed his ideas, he says "Well, one of the threads in the story is to trace a possible way a messiah is created in our society" and says the idea of Paul as a kind of avatar "was ignited by the idea of…by the ideas I encountered in reading about desert societies, and I think that the idea of the way Western society has exploited this force"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This post here deals with the same question as OP:

[Frank Herbert’s Dune Explained and Reviewed](https://amindformadness.com/2009/12/frank-herbert-dune-explained/)

> Here goes. The first thing I thought was that Dune was a metaphor for the Middle East.

But I don't think this is it. I believe answer is in the Herbert's own words:

> It began with a concept: to do a long novel about the messianic convulsions which periodically inflict themselves on human societies. I had this theory that superheroes were disastrous for humans, that even if you postulated an infallible hero, the things this hero set in motion fell into the hands of fallible mortals. What better way to destroy a civilization, society, or a race than to set people into the wild oscillations which follow their turning over their judgment and decision-making faculties to a superhero?

[Timothy O'Reilly](https://archive.org/details/frank-herbert-timothy-o-reilly/page/n1/mode/2up) writes that Herbert looked into Islam and Judaism for inspiration and, when one analyzes the words, names, titles etc., it shows words inspired by Arabic and Hebrew mostly (*Jihad*, *Kefitzat Haderech*).
In fact, Herbert chose Arabic mostly for the superficial reasons:

> If you want to give the reader the solid impression that he is not
> here and now, but that something of here and now has been carried to
> that faraway place and time, what better way to say to our culture
> that this is so than to give him the language of that place.... That
> oral tool - it has its own inertial forces; it's mind-shaping as well as
> used by mind.

O'Reilly also mentions that Herbert's research concluded that Islam fits best into the "periodic messianic convulsions" requirement. I personally see the logic, (albeit only because I remembered how I saw Islam, before I educated myself on it thoroughly), but I disagree thoroughly with these conclusions. Nevertheless, the Islamic inspirations are there, but mostly superficial - far more important to the plot is the society, which, as described by the book, matches more closely with European Feudalism than any other socio-political system, for example.

Regardless of my opinion, however, the Islam setting for *Dune* - for what it's worth -  is a deliberate choice due to the history of this specific religion and region it is associated with - desert - but most of all, for language and association it will create in readers' minds. But Fremen religion is also deeply steeped in ecology and it's science, which offers many possibilities for the story:

> I decided to put the two together because I don't think any story
> should have only one thread. I build on a layer technique, and of
> course putting in religion and religious ideas with ecological ideas
> you can play one against the other.

It is difficult to not see how this approach may split the reader audience on the opinion on how to interpret this elements of the story. And while it is entirely understandable to be confused by it and assume it's an allegory of the Middle East, the basic story presented in the book can be found all over the planet...

It is interesting to realize how many similarities there are between *Dune* and *Hamlet*, for example. But that's just one of many. The story of a Hero's rise and downfall, as well as his legacy's, can be found in every period and/or civilization, making it just a plot vehicle best suited to achieving Author's goal.

Comment: To be fair, educating oneself in Islam does not invalidate an allegory. It's fairly common for a religion's internal self-regard to be different from the way it manifest itself in real practice. As for the story being fairly common, I think that's where direct indicators (such as borrowed language) come into play. It would have been difficult for me to believe that FH did all that without intending or realizing that it would likely read as an unequivocal commentary on the Middle East.

Comment: Herbert also drew a lot on the book *The Sabres of Paradise* which was a Muslim leader in the Caucasus region, Imam Shamyl, whose warriors fought the Russian Empire (perhaps inspiring the Russian name of the villainous Harkonnens)--see [this post](https://arnoldkhan.medium.com/how-the-sabre-of-paradise-inspired-dune-f2b892c4869e) for ways that Herbert was influenced by the book. [This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/dune/comments/q6cqz4/frank_herberts_influences/hgckr0v/) on books known to have been in his library lists a number of other books on Muslim history and religion.

Comment: Another article on the influence of *The Sabres of Paradise* from the LA Review of books [here](https://lareviewofbooks.org/article/the-secret-history-of-dune/), and some more examples of specific quotes in Dune borrowed from the book [here](http://www.jacurutu.com/viewtopic.php?t=4054). Also see [this Tor.com article on "The Muslimness of Dune"](https://www.tor.com/2021/10/18/the-muslimness-of-dune-a-close-reading-of-appendix-ii-the-religion-of-dune/).

Comment: @MishaR - No, you're right, and that's what my answer is about - the veneer of Islam in *Dune* is by design - to stir a controversy. No question about it. However, when I mentioned an education in Islam, it was in the context of the "periodic Messianic convulsions". If he meant by that a coming of another "Messiah" (as in "Prophet"), then Islam is a definite no-no. But then again, Butlerian Jihad, seeking to overthrow the machines and returning to "godly" ways, well... it is Islamic shariah in a nutshell. But that's another topic and I mentioned it to shore up my opinion with a generality.

Comment: Is there any evidence that Herbert chose the elements of Islamic history to "stir a controversy" as opposed to other reasons like finding Islamic history especially interesting or especially relevant to the type of story he wanted to tell? And I don't understand why you say "the society" (by which you just seem to mean the Great Houses/Imperium) is evidence the Islamic inspirations are superficial, the Fremen society is also fleshed out in great detail, and conflict bt. the Fremen/Imperium could parallel conflict between some historical Islamic societies and others (like the Russian Empire).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Yeah, I may have read too much from what Herbert said about his process.. Let me think on how to rewrite this section, because I still believe he was aiming for the effect (generally speaking) of division of audience into two "camps", but maybe not exactly by stirring actual controversy. Please keep monitor this answer ;-)

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Oh, and on the other part of your comment - Fremen are desert wanderers, looking for their "promised land". Sounds like any Arabic/islamic story you're familiar with? However, it is a very well known story, is it? Islam offers no paradise on earth, doesn't it? Society at large - by which I mean the Galactic one, not Fremenm yes - is as far removed from any islam-related ones as possible with the settings of the story. Also - answer edited.

Comment: Fremen didn't have a belief in a promised land in a geographic sense, just in the sense of believing in Pardot Kynes' project of ecologically transforming Arrakis in the distant future, right? Been a little while since I read Dune but I don't remember this having any strong religious connotations for them (there wasn't a prophecy about it, was there?), I thought they just saw it as a long-term "construction project" of sorts. On the other hand, Paul being both a religious prophet and also a military leader has strong parallels with Muhammad in Islam.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Yes and no. Fremen did not originate on Arrakis, they were force-settled there. Before that they wandered from place to place looking for home. So in a sense, yes, they were promised a land, and no, it was not explicitly said they waited for Dune to transform to blue-green. But then again - what was the purpose of the *Lisan al gaib* of the prophecy? We know Fremen believed he was one but what he was supposed to do and how?

Comment: Looked up Zensunni on my kindle copy of Dune, it seems there is little information about the history of the Zensunni wanderers beyond some brief entries in the glossary, which do say it was a "forced migration" involving multiple planets, but I wouldn't say any refugee looking for a place to stay is searching for a "promised land" in a religious sense, and since they had been on Arakkis for thousands of years wouldn't they have just considered it their permanent home? As for Lisan al-Gaib, wasn't that one of the beliefs planted by Bene Gesserit so they'd have option to give Fremen a leader?

Comment: If it was a planted belief, the Bene Gesserit would probably not include any specific idea like leading the Fremen to a promised land unless that was part of their plan all along (but I don't remember anything in the books to suggest the BG had influenced Pardot Kynes). The entry in the glossary just says the Lisan al-Gaib was *“The Voice from the Outer World.” In Fremen messianic legends, an offworld prophet.* Making this position a specifically "offworld" one would allow the Bene Gesserity to bring any outsider they chose to fill the role and lead the Fremen for their own purposes.

Comment: Paul does say at one point say to Kynes "You have a legend of the Lisan al-Gaib here, the Voice from the Outer World, the one who will lead the Fremen to paradise." But leading them to paradise is a vague messianic statement that could mean a lot of things other than a new geographic home (like Paul's actual actions of leading them on a Jihad that gave them mastery over most of the known universe), the Bene Gesserit probably would have kept it intentionally vague, basically just "follow this person and great and blessed things will happen for your people".

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Well, that propecy may not be a Missionaria Protectiva plant, in fact - just like Fremen Reverend Mothers, it may predate this B.G. operation. It's just your assumption, because nowhere it says where it comes from. Lisan al-Gaib is not Kwisatz Haderach (and that second one Jessica identified as M.P. plant, true), to boot, though Fremen seem to mix it up, and apparently Kwisatz Haderach for them is literal shortening of their way to something, isn't it? Look up Kynes-Jessica conversation at the dinner... It certainly goes my way more than yours.

Comment: In-universe it could be argued it's a separate prophecy not from the Missionaria Protectiva, but since the question is about Herbert's intent, in Appendix III he does write 'It may be argued here that the Bene Gesserit sent their Missionaria Protectiva onto Arrakis centuries earlier to implant something like this legend' (talking about Paul being 'the voice from the outer world', i.e. the Lisan al-Gaib) and that this may have been why they didn't take the possibility of Paul being something outside of their plans seriously enough.

Comment: And good point about the Kynes-Jessica convo--before the dinner starts Leto says "One day, water will not be a precious commodity on Arrakis" and Kynes thinks of a prophecy that says "And they shall share your most precious dream" and asks Jessica "Do you bring the shortening of the way?" and Jessica thought to herself about how the phrase translated to "Kwisatz Haderach" and thought "Did our Missionaria Protectiva plant that legend here, too?" So that suggests the prophecy of the Kwisatz Haderach had some part about sharing a precious dream which Kynes interpreted in terms of the water plan.

Comment: Still, that doesn't suggest anything about whether the Lisan al-Gaib prophecy was or wasn't part of Missionaria Protectiva planted beliefs as well. Also, although Kynes interpreted it in terms of the existing water plan, the original Missionaria Protectiva planted prophecy may have left it open what the "precious dream" actually was. And Appendix III has hints of some higher force manipulating events which may have been using Missionaria Protectiva legends as part of a larger "plan" that the Bene Gesserit themselves were unaware of, creating synchronicities along these lines perhaps.

Comment: In terms of Herbert's intent again, I feel like if he had the idea that Fremen prophecies included the explicit dream of turning Arrakis into a water-rich world, he would have mentioned this in Appendix I which gave the history of how Pardot Kynes presented his plan for the ecological transformation of the planet to the Fremen, there was nothing there about them seeing it as significant that his idea matched one of their preexisting prophecies.

Answer (score 2):

Dune is certainly inspired by the Middle East. As other answers have mentioned there are linguistic poachings from Arabic in Fremen language and their lifestyles reflect tribal and nomadic patterns. Arrakis is basically a single biome desert planet aside from the poles.

However, OPEC is too late an influence in terms of both themes and publication. OPEC was founded in the early 1960's but didn't really throw its weight around or gain much non-specialist Western attention until the 1970's oil embargo sparked by the Yom Kippur War. Dune was published in 1965.

Instead the situation in Dune of heroic arabic outsiders resisting a mercantile and imperial elite reflects the earlier monopoly of the European imperial nations in exporting oil and using it for their military and commercial aims while subduing or sidelining native interests.

Paul Atreides comes in as a 'Lawrence of Arabia' type of saviour who unites the tribes and helps them defeat their oppressors with his civilised weaponry, heritage/breeding and strategic talents (alongside a heavy dose of sci-fi 'chosen one' charisma'). He turns the Fremen against the evil Harkonnen/Corrino imperials and brings in a new system that further both his and their aims.

Comment: This answer is one big opinion piece, and with the criteria applied, then Roman Empire and Jews fit even better, especially with the Roman strategy of depopulation of Palestine (remember, Rome ejected Jews from Jerusalem only; the reason why Palestine became Jew-free was genocide)... But the bottom line is that Paul Atreides came, gave them freedom and degenerated both Arrakis and Fremen... and then he went away and everything went downhill. But what to make of the Middle-Eastern uplift to civilization by Western powers in 1950s and 60s? What would be the paralell of that? Harkonnens?

Comment: @AcePL. Sure, any answer on influences is going to be opinionated - any seminal and historically-inspired work like this is going to draw on a number of sources.

Comment: I don't think the Judea/Roman comparison works as well as Arab/Empire though. Following Roman invasion, the Judean people had an intermittently rebellious province or defensive status until the disintegration of the empire and later invasions. The Arabs, by contrast, had a vigorous expansionist period following the rise of Islam which mirrors the Dune jihad.

Comment: But the alleged allegory is Arrakis and inhabitants and in that case, there is also the messianic element and struggle against the authority (generalizing here). I do not follow your logic on what in books you base your comparison. Is it the social order and structure?